# C++ list iterator

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate over the list using the iterator. The requirement is to get the previous element of a given element. But the condition is not to use two different iterators. I tried using prev(), but my professor said not use this function. Is there any other way for this?

My code is like this:

```
int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  std::list<int> mylist (myints,myints+5);

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
  //Print the current element
  //Print the previous element


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Don't use two iterators; don't use `std::prev`... this is sounding more like a lateral thinking puzzle than a normal programming task.

Comment: The way I interpret the description that you wrote in your question: either your professor, before giving the assignment, presented the relevant material in class and explained the relevant programming approaches that can be used to do this homework, or not. If the professor didn't teach anything relevant, before assigning this, then your professor is incompetent. If the professor did, then what part of the professor's explanation was unclear to you, or what is the actual cause for the inability of doing this assignment, were you absent from class the day it was taught, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::list` iterators are [bidirectional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), which means they support `operator--` and `operator++`. Since you are required to use only a single iterator, you can simply decrement it to access the previous element (as long as it is not pointing at the first element in the list), and then increment it back. For example:

```
int main () {
    int myints[] = {75, 23, 65, 42, 13};
    std::list<int> mylist (myints, myints+5);
    std::cout << "mylist contains:\n";
    for (std::list<int>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it;
        if (it != mylist.begin()) {
            std::cout << " (previous " << *(--it) << ")";
            ++it;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
int main () {
    int myints[] = {75, 23, 65, 42, 13};
    std::list<int> mylist (myints, myints+5);
    std::cout << "mylist contains:\n";
    std::list<int>::iterator it = mylist.begin();
    if (it != mylist.end()) {
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
        while (++it != mylist.end()) {
            std::cout << *it;
            std::cout << " (previous " << *(--it) << ")\n";
            ++it;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am against giving solutions to homework, but in this case I am doing an exception because whilst it is a full solution, for you it's half of solution. You can't really present to your professor with `std::optional` and you need to figure out how to do it without.

```
std::optional<int> prev;

for (auto it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); prev = *it, ++it)
{
    //Print the current element
    std::cout << *it;

    //Print the previous element
    if (prev)    
        std::cout << " " << *prev;

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unnecessarily, just do `std::cout << '\n'`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I know the arguments and I my humble opinion is that I will continue to use them. I am tired of how many times I had this argument. Take it as a personal preference.